# Defining a monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I am currently reading [Kan Extensions for Program Optimisation](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/Kan.pdf) and in the first page of the paper the author defines given M a monad the following monad

```
type C a = ∀z . (a → M z ) → M z
instance Monad C where
  return a = λc → c a
  m >>= k = λc → m (λa → k a c)
```

So I've tried to play a bit with it using M=Maybe hence writing the following code

```
type C a = forall z . (a -> Maybe z) -> Maybe z

instance Monad C where
  return a = \c -> c a
  m >>= k = \c -> m $ \a -> k a c
```

But it doesn't compile and outputs

> Main.hs:22:10: error:
> • The type synonym ‘C’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none

Which I am unable to interpret. What is wrong here ?
*(I've done some category theory but I've just started learning Haskell).*

Comment: In Haskell type synonyms cannot be partially applied, for complicated technical reasons. Make it a `newtype` instead.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've already (naively) tried doing so before but I got an other error. "Cannot parse data constructor in a data/newtype declaration"

Comment: Well I guess you made a typo on your syntax then

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I just replaced `type` with `newtype`. newtype C a = forall z . (a -> Maybe z) -> Maybe z

Comment: FYI this is an example of what is called the Continuation monad, which if you google you'll find lots of good references for. It takes a bit of getting your head around what it's doing and what it's useful for! (Your example specialises the `r` in `Cont r a` to be an instantiated type constructor `M z`, but there's no need for that in general - I presume there is in the wider context of the source you're quoting the definition from.)

Comment: @Julia You can't just replace the keyword `type` with `newtype`. `newtype` is more similar to `data` than it is to `type`; you need to define its constructor on the right hand side, not just write a type expression.

Comment: @Julia Research papers often give their examples in pseudo-code rather than actual code, exactly so they don't have to worry about things like the difference between `type` and `newtype`, and can just write down ideas. This example is pseudo-Haskell (the lambdas are a dead giveaway; `UnicodeSyntax` can give you the fancy arrows, but not `λ`). If you want to compile something similar you need to translate it into actual Haskell first. May I humbly suggest that "I've just started learning Haskell" is not the right experience level to be translating ideas from research papers into working code?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: The deeper reasons might be complicated, but there’s a fairly simple explanation. Partially applied type synonyms would let us make type-level closures. In turn, that would cause unreliable type inference (and worse error messages) when using higher-kinded types such as `Functor` and `Monad`.

Comment: It exists in a library [`Codensity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2.5/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need a `newtype`. `type` aliases are just programmer conveniences and aren't distinct entities, and you want to implement a typeclass, so you need a distinct entity. You can write the `newtype` like so.

```
newtype C a = C (forall z . (a -> Maybe z) -> Maybe z)
```

Though I would recommend including an accessor, because we'll need it for marshaling in a moment.

```
newtype C a = C { unC :: forall z . (a -> Maybe z) -> Maybe z }
```

(If you're following along at home, you need `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` to be able to do this `forall` syntax. It's a compiler extension that enables that particular fancier type)

To be clear, we're not going to write a `Monad` instance for `forall z. (a -> Maybe z) -> Maybe z`. That type doesn't belong to us. We're going to write a `Monad` instance for `C a`, a new type we just made up which *happens* to be isomorphic to `forall z. (a -> Maybe z) -> Maybe z` in a nice way.

Now [`Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) depends on [`Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) and [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Applicative), so we'll start there.

`Functor` is [derive-able](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/compiler/derive-functor), so we could just write `deriving (Functor)`, but it's also good practice to know how to write these out.

```
instance Functor C where
    fmap f (C a) = C $ \k -> a (k . f)
```

Now `Applicative`. It's very common to implement `Applicative` in terms of a corresponding `Monad` instance, so we'll do just that here.

```
instance Applicative C where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

(Note: `ap` comes from the `Control.Monad` module, so you'll want to import that as well)

This always works, provided you write the `Monad` instance so as not to call `pure` or `<*>`.

Now the `Monad`. It's pretty much exactly what you wrote, except with some `C` and `unC` marshaling to make the type checker happy.

```
instance Monad C where
    return a = C (\c -> c a)
    m >>= k = C (\c -> unC m $ \a -> unC (k a) c)
```

Finally, note that we never actually used `Maybe` or any of its properties here. Not only do we not care what that `M` is, we don't even need it to be a `Functor`. So we can parameterize by that as well.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad

newtype C m a = C { unC :: forall z . (a -> m z) -> m z }

instance Functor (C m) where
    fmap f (C a) = C $ \k -> a (k . f)

instance Applicative (C m) where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (C m) where
    return a = C (\c -> c a)
    m >>= k = C (\c -> unC m $ \a -> unC (k a) c)
```

Now `C Maybe` is identical to the `C` type you were just working with, but we can put anything of kind `* -> *` in place of the `m`. *Anything*, not just `Functor`s. Go wild.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use type aliases that are partially applied for instances. What is usually done in that case is working with a `newtype` that creates a new type, but is in essence only the type it wraps:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# Language UnicodeSyntax #-}

newtype C m a = C { getC :: ∀z . (a → m z ) → m z}
```

and then define the instance as:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (C m) where
  return a = C (\c -> c a)
  C m >>= k = C (\c -> m (\a -> getC (k a) c))
```

it thus does some wrapping and unwrapping in the `C` constructor, but these are essentially no-ops.